# Get All of Single Column from Every Table in Schema

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In our system, we have 1000+ tables, each of which has an 'date' column containing  DateTime object. I want to get a list containing every date that exists within all of the tables. I'm sure there should be an easy way to do this, but I've very limited knowledge of either postgresql or sqlalchemy.

In postgresql, I can do a full join on two tables, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do a join on every table in a schema, for a single common field.

I then tried to solve this programmatically in python with sqlalchemy. For each table, I did created a select distinct for the 'date' column, then set that list of selectes that to the selects property of a CompoundSelect object, and executed. As one might expect from an ugly brute force query, it has ben running now for an hour or so, and I am unsure if it has broken silently somewhere and will never return.

Is there a clean and better way to do this?

Comment: With the programatic method, you could at least start by outputting each select from each table into a separate table. This way you are able to see if your queries are still running or not.

Comment: Have you tried making the process threaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up reverting back to a previous solution of using SqlAlchemy to run the queries. This allowed me to parallelize things and run a *little* faster, since it really was a very large query.

I knew a few things with the dataset that helped with this query- I only wanted distinct dates from each table, and that the dates were the PK in my set. I ended up using the approach from [this wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan). Code being sent in the query looked like the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
(SELECT date FROM schema.tablename ORDER BY date LIMIT 1) 
UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT knowledge_date FROM schema.table WHERE date > t.date ORDER BY date LIMIT 1)
FROM t WHERE t.date IS NOT NULL)
SELECT date FROM t WHERE date IS NOT NULL;
```

I pulled the results of that query into a list of all my dates if they weren't already in the list, then saved that for use later. It's possible that it takes just as long as running it all in the pgsql console, but it was easier for me to save locally than to have to query the temp table in the db.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to do this on the server, not at the application level, due to the many round trips between application and server and likely duplication of data in intermediate results.

Since you need to process 1,000+ tables, you should use the system catalogs and dynamically query the tables. You need a function to do that efficiently:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_all_dates() RETURNS SETOF date AS $$
DECLARE
  tbl    name;
BEGIN
  FOR tbl IN SELECT 'public.' || tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' LOOP
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT DISTINCT date::date FROM ' || tbl;
  END LOOP
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This will process all the tables in the `public` schema; change as required. If the tables are in multiple schemas you need to insert your additional logic on where tables are stored, or you can make the schema name a parameter of the function and call the function multiple times and `UNION` the results.

Note that you may get duplicate `date`s from multiple tables. These duplicates you can weed out in the statement calling the function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM get_all_dates() ORDER BY 1;
```

The function creates a result set in memory, but if the number of distinct dates in the rows in the 1,000+ tables is very large, the results will be written to disk. If you expect this to happen, then you are probably better off creating a temporary table at the beginning of the function and inserting the dates into that temp table.

Comment: Created the function and sent it on its way! 20 minutes in, we'll have to see whether it completes. As an aside, there's a mising semicolon after your `END LOOP` that causes a syntax error if you put it in as-is.

Comment: @Lark If it takes that long, you are most likely better off using a `TEMP TABLE`. Using that you can also remove duplicates in the function.